# Declaring a integer inside a if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is my code so far

```
{     
    int x = 10;
    int p = 40;
    bool y = true;

    if (y == true)
    {
        int r = p;
    }

    {
        if (x + r >= 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Variables are greater than 100!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Variables are less than 100!");
        }
    }
```

Now I'm getting an error that says that "r" does not exist in the current context.

Im new to programming so no hate please!

Comment: Why are you using so many scopes?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Instead of asking, try explaining. He clearly states he's new to this. To the OP: The scopes, i.e. `{ }` are unnecessary in this context.

Comment: Please don't say `if(y == true)`. This means "if it is true that y is true". If you mean to say "if y is true" then just say that: `if(y)`. You didn't say `if(x+r>=100 == true)`, so why would you do that for `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is right, this code:

```
if (y == true)
{
    int r = p;
}
```

is indeed declaring the integer, but as soon as you close the block, the new variable, in this case `r`, ceases to exist. It is only visible to the `if` scope. Declare `r` just like you did with `x` and `p` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** as you have declared variable `r` inside `if block`, it will not be `accessible` outside the `if block`. because r becomes `local variable` to the `if-block`.

**Solution :** you need to move variable declaration of `r` outside the if block.so that variable `r` will be `available` everywhere within that `function` scope.

**Suggestion :**  you do'nt need to create extra code blocks using `curly braces` ,try to remove them.

Try This:

```
    int x = 10;
    int p = 40;
    bool y = true;
    int r = 0
    if (y == true)
    {
         r = p;
    }
    if (x + r >= 100)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Variables are greater than 100!");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Variables are less than 100!");
    }
```

**Suggestion :** if you really want to perform the above operation when `boolean` variable `y` becomes `true` you can simplify the above code without creating extra variable `r` as below:

Try This:

```
    int x = 10;
    int p = 40;
    bool y = true;       
    if (y == true && (x+p)>=100)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Variables are greater than 100!");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Variables are less than 100!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is..

```
    if (y == true)
    {
        int r = p; 
    }
```

Your "r" variable is declare in if clause, so it's only known in this clause, not for out side bracket. That's why in the next if clause the "r" variable is not defined.